# mocha webpack relative path resolver

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, webpack-dev-server

I have included webpack path resolver:

```
resolve: {
extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
root: [
  path.resolve('./src'),
]
```

My actual react components are coming up fine, but I have a problem with my test files. I have a test folder parallel to src folder where I have all my tests and there the resolver is not working and even If I give relative paths just in my test files - tests are not running as the actual components does not have '../../' instead they have - 'components/react-component.js' - how do I fix this issue for test folder?